# Creating a .csv file from three seperate list

Tags: r, list

Using the two list from below I would like to export a .csv file that has the values from `l2` and `l3` in their own seperate columns. Within those unique names in `l` there is a letter (e.g., A, B, C) and there is a number (e.g., 2001, 2002, 2003). I would to partition them so that the letters have its own column, and the number has a seperate column.

Expected Output:

| Letter | Number | Values from `l2` | Values from `l3` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2001 | 10 | 15 |
| B | 2002 | 11 | 16 |
| C | 2003 | 12 | 17 |

```
l <- list("A_2001","A_2001","B_2002","B_2002", "C_2003", "C_2003")

l2 <- list("1"= 10,
           "2" = 11,
           "3" = 12)

l3 <- list("1"= 15,
           "2" = 16,
           "3" = 17)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the input, we may `unlist` the `list` elements and create the data.frame with `read.table` and `transform` - get the `unique` elements of 'l', `unlist`, read with `read.table` specifying the `_` as `sep` to create a two column data.frame, then `unlist` the 'l2' and 'l3' to add new columns in the dataset

```
out <- transform(read.table(text = unlist(unique(l)), header = FALSE, 
    col.names = c("Letter", "Number"), sep = "_"),
    Values_from_l2 = unlist(l2), Values_from_l3 = unlist(l3))
```

-output

```
out
  Letter Number Values_from_l2 Values_from_l3
1      A   2001             10             15
2      B   2002             11             16
3      C   2003             12             17
```

Comment: Nice trick with `read.table`.

Comment: @r2evans why did you delete your post.  It seems to be different with `strsplit` though

Comment: Yeah, it's a brute-force approach that's no better than this.